# Oracle order by for different conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query and i would like to make two kinds of order based on a condition.

For example, if a field is NULL, i need to make an order and if it is not, i have to make another order. How i can do it ?

```
select *
  from table_1 t
  order by (if  t.field1 is null then
                   order by t.field2 DESC, field3 ASC
            else 
                  order by t.field4 ASC, field5 DESC)
```

This is a sample code: i want to make different order (ASC/DESC and different columns), based on the value of FIELD1

**EXAMPLE**

CONDITIONAL

```
ID FIELD1  FIELD2  FIELD3  FIELD4  FIELD5
1   1       2       3       4       5
2   NULL    6       7       8       9
```

DATA

```
ID PARENT_ID DATA1 DATA2 DATA3
1  1         X     Y     J
2  1         Z     W     U
3  2         XY    YX    O
4  2         ZW    WZ    I

select d.*
  from data d, conditional c
 where d.parent_id = c.id
   and d.parent_id = 1
order by
       case 
           when c.field1 is null then
              data1 asc, data2 desc
           else
              data3 asc, data1 desc
       end
```

In this example i select the DATA rows ONE and TWO (the rows that have parent id = 1).
Now that i have make this decision, i want to orther the DATA columns based on the value of CONDICTIONAL.FIELD1 column. I hope now is more clean.

Sure this query doesent work but this is "what i will need."

Comment: Can you give example data and an example output? As it is, it's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: `ASC` and `DESC` is entire resultset based.. not just that column.!

Comment: Edited the original answer with an example

Comment: @Mistre83, If your problem is resolved, would you please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have `CASE` construct in the `ORDER BY` clause :

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM EMP T
  2  ORDER BY
  3  CASE
  4     WHEN COMM IS NULL
  5     THEN SAL
  6     ELSE EMPNO
  7  END
  8  /

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950                    30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300                    10
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450                    10
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850                    30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000                    20
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000                    10
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500         30
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400         30
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0         30

14 rows selected.
```

**NOTE** : Take care of the `DATA TYPE` of the columns in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks this is a good start but, look at my original post update. Maybe i have forgot to give you some information.... i have two tables (or more) where one of this is needed to make "select" how to make the order. I have give an example on my post.

Comment: Check Alex's answer, he has expanded a bit further to answer your next question.

Answer (score 4):

As Lalit Kumar B said, use `case` within the `order by` clause. You can't specify two values or the asc/desc within the case, so you need to order by two case clauses that repeat the same condition:

```
select d.*
  from data d, conditional c
 where d.parent_id = c.id
   and d.parent_id = 1
order by
       case when c.field1 is null then d.data1 else d.data3 end asc,
       case when c.field1 is null then d.data2 else d.data1 end desc;
```

For your sample data that gives:

```
        ID  PARENT_ID DATA1 DATA2 DATA3
---------- ---------- ----- ----- -----
         1          1 X     Y     J     
         2          1 Z     W     U
```

Or with proper join syntax and avoiding `select *`:

```
select d.id, d.parent_id, d.data1, d.data2, d.data3
  from data d
  join conditional c
    on c.id = d.parent_id
 where d.parent_id = 1
order by
       case when c.field1 is null then d.data1 else d.data3 end asc,
       case when c.field1 is null then d.data2 else d.data1 end desc;
```

[Simple SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86d665/4).

Comment: I was about to edit and add more to my answer on OP's new request, but your answer is complete, so I don't have to do anything. Thanks ;-)

Comment: @LalitKumarB - I wasn't sure if you were going to expand yours. If you want to modify your answer I can delete this - don't mind either way.

Comment: Nope. Not required, you explained it quite nice. Let it be, since it gives better understanding of the flow of OP's questions and clarification. Thanks for your kind reply :-)

Comment: I have noticed that if i use two different type (NUMBER and DATE) in the when/the/else i got: PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

Comment: @Mistre83 - well, yes, the columns have to be the same type, or at least convertible to the same type. Your question doesn't suggest they wouldn't be. How would you - manually - decide whether 26-Sep-2014 comes before or after 42? The comparison doesn't make sense... If you can come up with a scheme that's meaningful then you can translate that to something Oracle can follow, but if *you* can't then the database can't.