# Is it possible to pass a column as a parameter to a ODER BY clause?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, parameters

I want to use a function in Oracle. But I need to ORDER BY accordingly with what the user pass as parameter.

Example:

```
FUNCTION foo_function(p_date IN DATE, p_column_number IN NUMBER)
RETURN foo_bar
IS
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM bar WHERE date = p_date ORDER BY p_column_number
   <...other code...>
END;
```

This block does not work. 
Is it possible to do something like this to pass the column as parameter to the ORDER BY clause?

UPDATE ----------

@XING shows a very good way to solve the problem without DECODE like the answers of other questions.

But the problem is that I'm missing something.
Now I'm getting this error: `"inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`

```
-- Creating my object with 2 columns.
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_OBJECT AS OBJECT(IDOP NUMBER, EMISSION_DATE DATE);

-- Creating the table of MY_OBJECT type.
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TB_OBJECT AS TABLE OF MY_OBJECT;

-- Creating my function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_OBJECT(
   P_INITIAL_DATE IN DATE,
   P_FINAL_DATE IN DATE,
   P_COLUMN_NUMBER   IN   NUMBER)
   RETURN TB_OBJECT
IS
   V_TB       TB_OBJECT;
   V_SQL      VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
   V_SQL :=
      'SELECT IDOP, EMISSION_DATE FROM OP WHERE EMISSION_DATE BETWEEN :p_initial_date AND :p_final_date ORDER BY :p_column_number';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL
   BULK COLLECT INTO V_TB
             USING P_COLUMN_NUMBER;

   RETURN (V_TB);
END;

-- Calling the function
SELECT * FROM TABLE (GET_OBJECT(TO_DATE('01/06/2017','dd/MM/yyyy'), TO_DATE('09/01/2018', 'dd/MM/yyyy'), 1));
```

UPDATE (2) ---------------------

The problem in my code is that I forget to cast the select to my object.

This way the code works.

```
V_SQL :=
      'SELECT MY_OBJECT(IDOP, EMISSION_DATE) FROM OP WHERE EMISSION_DATE BETWEEN :p_initial_date AND :p_final_date ORDER BY :p_column_number';
```

Thank you @XING

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate Dynamic Order by clause in PL/SQL procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043672/how-to-generate-dynamic-order-by-clause-in-pl-sql-procedure)

Comment: Hi, you need to research dynamic SQL https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in the below example i show you how to do that in a function by only ordering only 1 column. You can modify the function as per your need;

```
--Created a type of number to return the ordered result. You can create an object with the column same as used in your select statement.
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE VAR_RET AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/
```

--Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FOO_FUNCTION (     
     P_COLUMN_NUMBER   IN   NUMBER)
     RETURN VAR_RET
IS
     V_RES                         VAR_RET;
     v_sql                         VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
     V_SQL :=
          'SELECT EMPNO FROM EMP   ORDER BY :p_column_number'; --<-- Create Object with all the columns you are selecting here and then a type of your object to hold result

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL
     BULK COLLECT INTO V_RES
                 USING P_COLUMN_NUMBER;

     RETURN (V_RES);
END;
```

--Result:

```
SQL>  select * from table( FOO_FUNCTION (1));

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
        7369
        7499
        7521
        7566
        7654
        7698
        7782
        7788
        7839
        7844
        7876
```

EDIT: WITH 2 COLUMNS Ordering

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TAB AS OBJECT
(
 V_EMPNM   VARCHAR2(100),
 V_EMPNO   NUMBER
);

CREATE OR REPLACE  TYPE VAR_RET AS TABLE OF MY_TAB;
/



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FOO_FUNCTION (     
     P_COLUMN_NUMBER   IN   NUMBER)
     RETURN VAR_RET
IS
     V_RES                         VAR_RET;
     v_sql                         VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
     V_SQL := --You need to cast your select statement as per Object
          'SELECT MY_TAB(ENAME,EMPNO) FROM EMP ORDER BY :p_column_number'; --<-- Create Object with all the columns you are selecting here and then a type of your object to hold result

     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL
     BULK COLLECT INTO V_RES
                 USING P_COLUMN_NUMBER;

     RETURN (V_RES);
END;
```

Execution:
1) Way 1

```
DECLARE
     VAR                           VAR_RET := VAR_RET ();
BEGIN
     VAR := FOO_FUNCTION (1);

     FOR I IN 1 .. VAR.COUNT
     LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (VAR (I).V_EMPNM ||'  ' ||VAR (I).V_EMPNO);
     END LOOP;
END;

SQL> /
SMITH  7369
ALLEN  7499
WARD  7521
JONES  7566
MARTIN  7654
BLAKE  7698
CLARK  7782
SCOTT  7788
KING  7839
TURNER  7844
ADAMS  7876
JAMES  7900
FORD  7902
MILLER  7934

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

2) WAY 2

```
 select * from table( FOO_FUNCTION (1));

V_EMPNM                                                                                                 V_EMPNO
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SMITH                                                                                                      7369
ALLEN                                                                                                      7499
WARD                                                                                                       7521
JONES                                                                                                      7566
MARTIN                                                                                                     7654
BLAKE                                                                                                      7698
CLARK                                                                                                      7782
SCOTT                                                                                                      7788
KING                                                                                                       7839
TURNER                                                                                                     7844
ADAMS                                                                                                      7876

V_EMPNM                                                                                                 V_EMPNO
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JAMES                                                                                                      7900
FORD                                                                                                       7902
MILLER                                                                                                     7934

14 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks @XING your answer solves my problem like a charm.

Comment: If I want a table of a object, I only need to create first the MY_OBJECT and then set the type (VAR_RET at your example) of table as MY_OBJECT.
Is that correct?

Comment: @Odilon Exactly correct but you simply cannot declare a variable of object. After creating a Object you create a type of your object. Like i created a type of table Number in my example. Try it and let me know if you face any issue

Comment: I updated the question @XING . I'm missing something, because my function does not work with more than one column.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works very well. I forget to cast the select to my object.