# ORACLE SQL it is possible to customize the order result of a query?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a case in which I need to order the query result in a customized order like the following :

[image]

the `DEPARTEMENT_ID` needs to be in this order ( 10 then 50 then 20 )

is there a way to get this result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **CASE** expression in the **ORDER BY** clause.

I answered a similar question here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26033176/3989608, you could just tweak it to have your customized conditions in the CASE expression.

For example,

```
SQL>  SELECT   ename,
  2           deptno
  3  FROM     emp
  4  ORDER BY
  5           CASE deptno
  6                    WHEN 20 THEN 1
  7                    WHEN 10 THEN 2
  8                    WHEN 30 THEN 3
  9           END
 10  /

ENAME          DEPTNO
---------- ----------
SMITH              20
FORD               20
ADAMS              20
JONES              20
SCOTT              20
CLARK              10
KING               10
MILLER             10
ALLEN              30
TURNER             30
WARD               30
MARTIN             30
JAMES              30
BLAKE              30

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do it is to have an other column DISPLAY_ORDER having serial number data in the order that you want it.

so the sql will be

```
select JOB_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID 
from EMPLOYEES
order by DISPLAY_ORDER;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DECODE` to accomplish this.

```
SELECT JOB_ID,DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM YOURTABLE
ORDER BY DECODE(DEPARTEMENT_ID, 10, 1, 50, 2, 20, 3,4)
```

Refer to these threads below for more information.

[Custom Order in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339589/custom-order-in-oracle-sql)

[DECODE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm)